# comparar valores dentro de un arreglo, dentro de un while

Tags: php

Buenas amigos aqui nuevamente con una duda, recurriendo a los dioses XD.

tengo una variable que evaluar para que cuando se repita, realice una accion.

el programa se abastece con datos cada vez que un bucle de control (while) da una vuelta, entonces cada vuelta me trae un valor distinto de la base de datos.

```
$SQL = "SELECT fecha,
        despacho_kilos,
        despacho_pesos,
        indaval_kilos,
        indaval_pesos,
        arco_kilos,
        arco_pesos
        FROM ventas_stgo
        WHERE fecha
        LIKE '%{$AnioMes}%' LIMIT 0,50 ";  //consulta SQL con filtro de fechas.

$result = mysqli_query($conexion->conectarse(), $SQL);

$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$vuelta = 1;
```

> *no pongo el codigo html para no agrandar el post.*

```
$valores = '<table rules="all" cellspacing="0"   id="data"  class="data" name="data" style="float:left; margin-bottom:40px;">
</thead>
    <tbody>';
$zr=0;while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$nrodia=date('N', strtotime($row['fecha']));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he creado una funcion para que por cada vuelta me imprima el dia al cual corresponde el puntero, de ese modo imprimo el dia como se ve en la imagen destacado con amarillo.

```
function saber_dia($nombredia)
                {                                                                                                               //funcion para saber el dia segun fecha
$dias = array('Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado');
$fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($nombredia))];
        return $fecha;
            }
```

luego paso el el dato de la bd ($row['fecha']; por la funcion y me entrega el dia.

```
$temp = saber_dia($row['fecha']);
```

luego la variable `$temp`

entrega estos datos:

```
echo $temp; // returns : LunesMartesMiercolesJuevesViernesLunesMartesMiercolesJuevesViernesLunesLunesMartesMiercolesJuevesViernesLunes
```

lo paso por `json_encode()` para agregar comillas...

```
echo json_encode($temp); // returns "Lunes""Martes""Miercoles""Jueves""Viernes""Lunes""Martes""Miercoles""Jueves""Viernes""Lunes""Lunes""Martes""Miercoles""Jueves""Viernes""Lunes"
```

> lo hago suponiendo que con json_encode es mas facil trabajar los strings, aunque no lo se realmente... acepto criticas por  buenas practicas.

entonces, como pueden ver en los resultados de la variable `$temp`  me entrega esos valores, al fin de cada semana, imprimo un valor semanal como aparece en la imagen, pero no me considera ese lunes 16 (antes del lunes 23) que esta, debería imprimir un total semanal despues de el lunes 16, se que para eso tengo que validar que si el dia que esta pasando se repite, se debe imprimir un total semanal.
 no he intentado validarlo, por que no si se debo hacerlo dentro del while o en una funcion aparte. disculpen mi poca experiencia.
pero en realidad mi poca experiencia me limita llegar a mi solucion.
cualquier ayuda o sugerencia es bienvenida.

de ante mano gracias Coders!

PD: tengo tambien una variable que me muestra el indice de cada dia con respecto a dias habiles de la semana, en donde me entrega solo el numero del dia.

```
echo json_encode($array);  // returns ["1"]["2"]["3"]["4"]["5"]["1"]["2"]["3"]["4"]["5"]["1"]["1"]["2"]["3"]["4"]["5"]["1"]
```

si se puede validar con eso, igual es valido, podria ser creo, que si el numero actual de la variable `$array` es igual o mayor que la misma variable `$array(+1)` 
nose como seria esa instruccion.. 
para situarme una pocision adelante del puntero. intente con `pos(), Next() y prev()` pero sin resultados.
gracias.

> determino si poner un total semanal asi :

```
    $zr=0;

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))   //mientras que la variable $result siga obteniendo valores, creara celdas y filas necesarias dentro de una tabla asignando los valores solicitados en la columna $row, desde la bd. aplicando una relacion entre nombres de tablas
                                {
                                $nrodia=date('N', strtotime($row['fecha']));
                            if ($zr < $nrodia ){
                                $zr=$nrodia;
                                }
                            if($nrodia < $zr )  {
                                $zr=$nrodia;


                            $valores = $valores."<tr style='font-weight:bold;  background:#FFD2D2' >
                            <td style='color:black;' style='text-align:center' background:#FFD2D2' >TOTAL SEMANAL</td>
                            ".$resultadoKilos."
                            ".$resultadoPesos."
                            ".$resultado_KI."
                            ".$resultado_PI."
                            ".$resultado_KA."
                            ".$resultado_PA."
                            ".$resultado_KD."
                            ".$resultado_PD."
                            <td class='border-td' style='background-color: rgb(255,255,255);' 'text-align:center;'>-</td>
                            </tr>";
```

Comment: Con qué función estás determinando si poner o no el "total semanal"?

Comment: despues de declarar la variable variable $zr = 0;

Comment: la comparo con el valor que entrega la otra funcion para obtener la fecha. de este modo imprimo el total semanal cuando  el numero de dia es menor al siguiente, considerando los dias de la semana. pero en este caso, es una semana entera de diferencia, en donde solo se trabajo el lunes,  se que deberia comparar el dia del puntero con el siguiente y ahi imprimir, pero nose como.. :(

Comment: Me perdí entre tantas explicaciones sin llegar a entender cuál era el problema.

Comment: puede continuar navegando amigo, gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perdón la demora, mi solución, para no seguir indagando mas a fondo, fue cumplir con lo que hace el sistema, evalúo si un día es menor que el anterior, si es menor, salta la semana, en este caso solo tenia un lunes, y no podía comprarlo solo, así que agregue un día martes con valores de producción en 0, asi no choca con la producción. es poco ortodoxo, pero funcional, gracias por darse el tiempo de leer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]